# Would knowing that exactly 14 out of the first 20 coin tosses are heads change the probabilty that exactly 7 out of the first 10 tosses are heads?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Assume that the coin is fair and is tossed an infinitely number of times, independently.

In the original version of this question, the former event is "9 out of the first 20 coin tosses are heads", and given that fact, the probability of the latter event is indeed lower. I thought it was because the 9 heads, being distributed amongst the 20 coin tosses, would make it less likely for a large portion of them, namely 7, to be present in the first 10 tosses.

If so, I think it'd make sense that knowing that 14 out of the first 20 coin tosses are heads would have no effect on the probability of the desired event. But the Bayes' theorem doesn't seem to say so. Below is my working out in details of the problem:

> Let $Y$ be the event that exactly 7 out of the first 10 tosses are
> heads, and $Z$ the event that exactly 14 out of the first 20 tosses
> are heads. Then: $$P(Y) = {10 \choose 7} \frac{1}{2^{10}} \approx
> 0.117$$ $$P(Z) = {20 \choose 14} \frac{1}{2^{20}}$$ $$\text{and } P(Z|Y) = {10 \choose 7} \frac{1}{2^{10}} \text{, }$$ as given that
> exactly 7 out of the first 10 tosses are heads, $P(Z|Y)$ is just the
> probability that exactly 7 out of the last 10 tosses are heads. Then:
> $$P(Y|Z) = \frac{P(Y\cap Z)}{P(Z)} = \frac{P(Z|Y)P(Y)}{P(Z)} = \frac{{10
> \choose 7}{10 \choose 7}}{20 \choose 14} \approx 0.372 \neq P(Y)$$

Where did my intuition/calculation go wrong?

Comment: Intuitively, event $Y$ isn't that likely because we expect ~5 heads. But, if we knew we got a lot of heads, then event $Y$ would indeed be more likely.

Comment: Given $14$ out of $20$, we expect $7$ heads in the first $10$.  Without the given event, we'd expect $5$, so the expected number of Heads in the first $10$ is higher than it would otherwise be...hence, I'd find it intuitive that the individual probabilities have changed as well (clearly some of them have).  But intuition for these things is slippery, and the actual computation is more reliable.

Comment: I think the following situation is more intuitive: if you know that 20 out of the first 20 coin tosses are heads, does it change the probability that 10 out of the first 10 tosses are heads? Obviously quite a bit. To me the situations are similar, just differing in scale.

Comment: It's easy to see what's happening with smaller numbers. The probability of exactly one head in two tosses is one-half. If there are exactly two heads in four tosses, that could be HHTT, HTHT, HTTH, THHT, THTH, TTHH, making the probability of exactly one head in the first two tosses two-thirds. So I think it has nothing to do with the explanations others are giving. (Note the probability of exactly one tail in the first two tosses, given exactly two heads in four tosses, is also two-thirds).

Comment: @lulu, "Given 14 out of 20, we expect 7 heads in the first 10. Without the given event, we'd expect 5, so the expected number of Heads in the first 10 is higher than it would otherwise be..." If we change seven heads to five, and 14 heads to ten, then this reasoning doesn't apply, but 5 in the first ten is still more likely given 10 in 20 than it is without, $.3437$ against $.2461$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Not sure I see your point.  My point was that, as the expectations have changed, the individual probabilities must have changed as well.  I certainly agree that intuiting the changes of the individual probabilities is difficult and probably not worth the effort.  But the OP was just asking if the conditioning would have some impact on the indiviudal probabilities and I do think that's clear...

Comment: @lulu, in my scenario, the expectations *don't* change, but the indiividual probabilities change anyway. Given 10 out of 20, we expect 5 in the first ten. Without the given event, we'd expect 5, so the expected number of heads in the first 10 isn't higher than it would otherwise be ... but the individual probabilities change anyway. Your explanation of the change no longer applies, but the change happens anyway. So it must be something other than your explanation that actually explains the change.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Ah, I see.  Though of course different scenarios might have different explanations....I still think that the expectation argument is a quick way to see that some probabilities *must* have changed.  It is interesting that, in your case, the individual probabilities conspire to match the expectation.  I'll take a look at that...

Comment: I think a better explanation of why knowing 14 out of 20 increases the probability of 7 of the first 10 is that if 14 of the 20 are heads then at least 4 of the first 10 must be heads. We have eliminated the possibilities that there were no heads, or exactly one head, or exactly two heads, or exactly three heads, in the first ten, so it stands to reason that we have increased the probabilities of the remaining possibilities, such as exactly seven heads.

Comment: If you are still here, ensbana, do you have anything to say about the discussion we've been having in your absence? or about the answer that was posted in December (but recently deleted by its author)?